# React open and close menu using onBlur and onFocus failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tried create a dropdown menu use onFocus and onBlur. There's a reason for that I don't use onClick because with onFocus and onBlur I need not to close the menu manually if I have multiples dropdowns, eg I click on menu one, the opened menu 2 will be closed. But I have one problem, I can't make checkbox work if it's a part of the menu content.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dL99rx27/

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {
         open: false
      }
    }

   render() {
      return(
      <div
        tabIndex="1"
        onFocus={() => this.setState({open: true})}
        onBlur={() => this.setState({open: false})}
      >
        <p>Menu</p>
        <div style={this.state.open === false ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'} }>
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
        </div>
      )
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
          <Dropdown>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 1')}>link 1</li>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 2')}>link 2</li>
            <input type="checkbox" label="check"/>
          </Dropdown>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How to not trigger onBlur to avoid the menu content being closed when user clicked on the checkbox?

Comment: Only one element can have focus at a time. So when you click on `checkbox`, the focus shifts from div to `checkbox`. So you either have a callback from child to parent to tell its still in focus, or change your architecture.